# Extract Download Link from HTML in R Shiny app

Tags: html, r, shiny

I'm trying to download the data file posted on the following website:

https://data.aclum.org/sjc-12926-tracker/

Originally I just called

`download.file("https://data.aclum.org/sjc-12926-tracker/session/b6c83d85236fc1950a06c5eda2ed6746/download/downloadData?w=", destfile="MADoc.xlsx")`

and it would save to my working directory. However, the URL download path keeps changing, since they update the file every day. I can see the html code for the webpage to download the link when I inspect the element, but I can't figure out how to extract it (sorry--very new to using html code). Does anyone have a solution? Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This web is a [Shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/) app, so:

- the link is changing every session and is dynamically created (in HTML it's empty, it needs to run some javascript), so its hard to webscrape, but
- you can browse the [source code](https://github.com/ACLUmass/sjc-12926-covid-19) and get a hack. The data is stored in [Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nmZ84rjOxQgdTL0PdV7SrbyDTbD7nROQ/edit#gid=1419540291):

```r
# you may need to install.packages("tidyverse")
library(httr)
library(readxl)

# get data from server
GET("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nmZ84rjOxQgdTL0PdV7SrbyDTbD7nROQ/export#gid=1419540291",
    write_disk(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")))
#> Response [https://doc-10-3g-sheets.googleusercontent.com/export/l5l039s6ni5uumqbsj9o11lmdc/dcg0ddist9t9r6tkjmfpr6d3jk/1593757275000/102387500909510694712/*/1nmZ84rjOxQgdTL0PdV7SrbyDTbD7nROQ]
#>   Date: 2020-07-03 06:21
#>   Status: 200
#>   Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
#>   Size: 456 kB

data <- read_excel(tf)

head(data)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 19
#>   Date                County `Pre-Trial Popu~ `Sentenced Popu~ `Other Populati~
#>   <dttm>              <chr>  <chr>            <chr>            <chr>           
#> 1 2020-03-27 00:00:00 DOC    NA               NA               NA              
#> 2 2020-03-31 00:00:00 DOC    NA               NA               NA              
#> 3 2020-04-04 00:00:00 Brist~ 438              262              NA              
#> 4 2020-04-05 00:00:00 Barns~ 89               115              NA              
#> 5 2020-04-05 00:00:00 Berks~ 77               92               NA              
#> 6 2020-04-05 00:00:00 Brist~ 436              259              NA              
#> # ... with 14 more variables: `Total Population` <chr>, `N Tested -
#> #   Detainees/Inmates` <chr>, `N Positive - Detainees/Inmates` <chr>, `N Tested
#> #   - COs` <chr>, `N Positive - COs` <chr>, `N Tested - Staff` <chr>, `N
#> #   Positive - Staff` <chr>, `N Tested - Contractors` <chr>, `N Positive -
#> #   Contractor` <chr>, `Total Tested` <chr>, `Total Positive` <chr>, `N
#> #   Released Pre-Trial` <chr>, `N Released Sentenced` <chr>, Notes <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks so much! How did you find the source code on the page? No worries if that's too complicated to explain. I don't think I need to do this for any of the other websites I'm scraping for this project but just for future reference it would be great. Thanks so much @Petr!

Comment: @babybonobo Hi, thanks for your feedback, I'm glad it works for you! After all, it's quite short: I saw link to GitHub on [their page](https://data.aclum.org/sjc-12926-tracker/) (section SOURCE CODE in the text). I did some Shiny apps, so I am quite familiar with the structure. I looked into [app.R](https://github.com/ACLUmass/sjc-12926-covid-19/blob/master/app.R) file, explored what the [download button](https://github.com/ACLUmass/sjc-12926-covid-19/blob/master/app.R#L1837-L1849) does and [where it takes data](https://github.com/ACLUmass/sjc-12926-covid-19/blob/master/app.R#L662-L669).

Comment: that's a great explanation, thanks so much for going through it! I appreciate you taking the time to walk me through this! Thanks again!